# How to access DataGridView data

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Bit of a generic title, but I wasn't exactly sure how to summarize the situation:

I have a DGV with several rows and 6 columns. On the form with this DGV, I have a few buttons to Add, Edit, Delete, and Save the state of the DGV (Figure 1). When a user clicks the Edit button, a new window is opened with TextBoxes which should be filled with the data from the selected row (Figure 2).

My question is, what is the best method for passing the row's data (either through DataGridViewRow or DataGridViewCellCollection), and once it's been passed to the Edit class, how can I access the row's data. Once I can receive this, the rest should be cake for me, but I am unsure of how to access the cells' datas.

Code posted below images.

Figure 1: [image: Main form with DGV & buttons]

Figure 2: (Not sure why it's so huge, sorry!)

[image: Edit window for cell data]

CODE SNIPPETS:

Here is the code for the DGV's Edit Rail Car button:

```
private void buttonEditRailCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var singleCarSelected = this.dataGridViewSimulatedTrainEditor.CurrentRow;

        EditRailCar editNewRailCar = new EditRailCar(singleCarSelected);

        //To StackOverFlow: Feel free to ignore anything below this comment!

        var result = editNewRailCar.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {                
            this.NewSimulatedTrain.Add(addNewRailCar.NewSimulatedTrain);
            this.WereChangesMade = true;
            this.buttonSaveXML.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the Edit Rail Car FORM that pops up with the textboxes I will populate with the data from the row - I've added some pseudocode so you can see what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public partial class EditRailCar : Form
{
    public EditRailCar(DataGridViewRow t)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Here, when the form opens, the local textboxes should be populated with data
            //from the DGV's cells
        this.textBoxName.Text = t.RailCarName;
        this.textBoxRailCarType.Text = t.RailCarType;
        this.textBoxVelocity.Text = t.Velocity;
        this.textBoxVelocityDistance.Text = t.VelocityDistance;
        this.textBoxIsDamaged.Text = t.IsDamage;
        this.textBoxIsForeignObject.Text = t.IsForeignObject;
    }

    private void buttonSaveEdits_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This will save the changes to the current row in the DGV
        //StackOverFlow may ignore this :)
    }

    private void buttonCancelNewCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```

Comment: This line is wrong `this.dataGridViewSimulatedTrainEditor.CurrentRow`

Comment: Should I use the .SelectedCells instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `SelectedRows` property instead of `CurrentRow` of datagridview like

```
if (this.dataGridViewSimulatedTrainEditor.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    var singleCarSelected = this.dataGridViewSimulatedTrainEditor.SelectedRows[0];
}
```

Again the way you are passing is completely wrong. rather create a `RetailCar` type , fill it and pass it along like

```
public class RetailCar
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Type {get; set;}

  // rest propetties
}

DataGridViewRow rw = this.dataGridViewSimulatedTrainEditor.SelectedRows[0];
RetailCar rc = new RetailCar
{
  Name = rw.Cells["RetailCar Name"].Value.ToString();
  Type = rw.Cells["RetailCar Type"].Value.ToString();

  // fill rest properties
};
```

Pass it along

```
EditRailCar editNewRailCar = new EditRailCar(rc);
```

Change your form constructor accordingly

```
public partial class EditRailCar : Form
{
    public EditRailCar(RetailCar retailCar)
    { 
        // do whatever needed
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, I went through and mimicked this solution, and it looks like it worked quite well! Hat off to you Rahul! I am curious though, if we set rw to the same thing as singleCarSelected, what is the purpose of having the singleCarSelected variable still be present? would it not be more intuitive to move the rw assignment to the IF statement and have it be set there?

Comment: @AlexWatts, I meant that only. It's just an example to show. It's a 2-part suggestion. first I wanted to say use selectedrows and then wanted to show how to pass data.